# Why is the CT system $y(t)=x(2t)$ invertible but its DT counterpart non-invertible?

Tags: functions, inverse

Just for clarity, a system is invertible if distinct inputs lead to distinct outputs.

That said, I have two systems, a continuous time system and a discrete time system:

(1) $y(t) = x(2t)$ (Continuous time) and

(2) $y[n] = x[2n]$ (Discrete Time)

I know that the CT system is invertible, $y(t) = x(t/2)$. However, my book says that the DT system is not invertible, citing that $x_{1}[n]=\delta[n-1] \rightarrow y[n] = 0$ and $x_{2}[n]=0 \rightarrow y[n] = 0$. Seeing that these two distinct inputs yield the same output, I see that it's not invertible.

My question, then, is why doesn't the same counter-example used to show that the DT system isn't invertible work on the CT system? That is, why doesn't $x_{1}(t) =\delta(t-1) \rightarrow y(t) = 0$ and $x_{2}(t)=0 \rightarrow y(t) = 0$?

I suspect that there is a fundamental difference between CT and DT delta functions that I'm missing. From my book, it states that $\delta[n] \equiv 0$ if $n \neq 0$, $1$ if $n = 0$. For CT, $\delta(t) = \frac{du(t)}{dt}$, where $u(t)$ is the unit step function.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a way to think of it: the discrete system "loses information" in order to give you $x[2n]$, i.e. it "throws out" all the values of $x$ at odd $n$.  The continuous system takes all the information and compresses it, without losing any.  In a continuous system, we can always find $x(t/2)$.  We can't always find $x[n/2]$ in a discrete system.

Comment: That's a good way of thinking about it - there's no way to recover the values of $x$ at odd $n$. Still, I'm mulling over the difference between the CT and DT counter-examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CT system, we would calculate
$$
y[\delta(t-1)] = \delta(2t - 1)
$$
whereas 
$$
y[0] = 0
$$
Note that $\delta(2t - 1) \neq 0$.  In particular, this function is "non-zero" at $t = 1/2$.

In the discrete system, there is no "$n = 1/2$" that would cause distinction between the two outputs.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.